# Heading image or string?

Tags: image, livecode

I just created a page which the user can choose the mode to show, such as icon (image) or just temperature (text). Those are my code:

```
<?lc
#tell the browser that we will send binary data (png)
put header("Content-type:image/png")

#get ip address
if $_GET["ip"] = "" then
    put $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] into ipAddress
else 
    put $_GET["ip"] into ipAddress
end if

#get the mode
put $_GET["mode"] into mode

#get longtitude and latitude data
put url ("http://vo.afteroffice.com/r/v/public/pub/geoloc?ip=" & ipAddress) into geoInfo
        split geoInfo by cr and ":"

#input lon and lat data into url
put url ("http://api.yr.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.8/?lat=" & geoInfo["latitude"] & ";lon=" & geoInfo["longtitude"]) into weatherDetail

#create tree from XML data
put revCreateXMLTree(weatherDetail, false, true, false) into tLocation

#get data about temperature and clouds
put revXMLAttribute(tLocation,"weatherdata/product/time/location/temperature", "value") into temperature

#create the output
if mode = "temperature" then
        put "The temperature is " & temperature
    else if mode = "icon" then
        put URL("binfile:icon/hot01.png")
    else if mode = "" then
        put "Oke"
end if
?>
```

My image & text problems are:

- If I don't put `put header("Content-type:image/png")` in my code and I call mode=icon, the result will be "‰PNG  IHDRPPŽò­tEXtSoftwareAdobe ImageReadyqÉe
- If I put `put header("Content-type:image/png")` in my code and I call mode=temperature, the result will be "Te image cannot displayed, cause it contains error"

Could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Don't `put header()` until the end where you know which type you are going to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And how about adding something like

```
if mode = "temperature" then 
# do not put header
else if mode = "icon" then
put header("Content-type:image/png")
end if
```

at the position where you have your content type header now?

You just have to add the definition of `mode` at the beginning instead of the middle of your script

Comment: could you give me article suggestion how to create a web cache using livecode?